# How to drop a table in spatialite that starts with a certain string?

Tags: spatialite, table

I am using spatialite (v4.2.0) on a Windows 7 (64bit) PC.  I need a way to drop a specific table that always begins with "_old" from my database.  The file may not be in the database in the first place.  I do not know the rest of the table name since it can change (ex:  _old_20140801, or _old_20140715, etc.).  I can always find out if a table that fits my criteria exists with the command:

```
.tables '_old%'
```

but how do I save that result (is it storable in a local variable?) and then use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an alternate way:  instead of using .tables, use a select statement on the sqlite_master table.  Store the result of the select statement in a file.  Create a local variable that stores the file content and use this in the drop statement. (you could probably skip the storage in the csv file using local variables, but I don't know how to do this yet).

```
spatialite c:\temp.sqlite "SELECT name from sqlite_master where (type = 'table' and name like'_pole_old%');" > c:\old_pole.csv
(set /p var1=)<c:\old_pole.csv
spatialite c:\temp.sqlite "drop table if exists %var1%;"
```